# Keep Python Command window open on Windows

Tags: python, windows

Ok I know this has been asked/answered a bunch of times, but the solutions are not working in my situation.  I created a Python script using 2.7 on a headless linux terminal on a Raspberry Pi, it works perfectly in that environment.
The script contains an sqlite3 database.  On my Windows 10 machine, if I simply double click the Python script from Desktop it creates the database.db file, but the Python command prompt closes before I can see the output.

Running the Python script from the Windows Command prompt eg 'start C:\Users\User\Desktop\script.py'  does exactly the same thing

Using Run and 'cmd /k C:\Users\User\Desktop\script.py'  does make the Command window persist, but then it errors on the line opening the sqlite3 database:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\script.py", line 91, in <module>
    conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The reason Im on Windows at all is Im trying to build a GUI with Tkinter and my R Pi has no GUI, help appreciated

Comment: You don't need `cmd /k` or `start`. Just run run `C:\Users\User\Desktop\script.py` in a command prompt.

Comment: OK thanks that has worked, I have become used to Linux command line and having trouble adjusting to Windows

Comment: In fact its not working, the Python Script does not execute correctly with this method, if database.db is missing the user must input to create the database, this does not occur using the above method

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Add `input(os.getpid())` at the start of your program to print the PID and make it wait. Then in [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), check the "Image" tab in the properties of the process for the path, command line, and current directory. What changes when you don't use `start`?

Comment: I finally figured this out, I had to add Python as a path in PATH, it now works simply using C:\Users\User\Desktop\script.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full path like `C:\Users\User\Desktop\database.db`.

The reason is when running from 'cmd /k C:\Users\User\Desktop\script.py' then the working directory where the command is called is different and it tries to look `database.db` in that folder, and gives you the error.

You can check what the present `dir` is by :

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Comment: If database.db is in the script directory, you can use `path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'database.db')`, or instead of `__file__` you can use `sys.argv[0]`. The latter should work in a frozen executable, such as from py2exe or pyinstaller.

Comment: The python script will request user input if the database.db is missing and create the database if its not found in the directory where the python script is executed from.  This works perfectly if I double click the script.py but I cant see the output.  All these other methods the database.db creation/detection is not working.